# MBProgressHud is not changing with device orientation.?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, device-orientation, mbprogresshud

I am using MBProgressHud to show a loading indicator on a splash view but this does not change with device orientation. My code is:

```
splashView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.frame];

 if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
 {
  splashView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DefaultPad.png"];  
 }
 else
 {
    splashView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];  
 }

  hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc]initWithView:splashView];
  [splashView addSubview:hud];

  hud.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
  hud.labelText = @"Loading...";

  [hud show:YES];

 [self.window addSubview:splashView];
 [self performSelector:@selector(Load_FirstView) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

and I have changed the line in `MBProgressHud.m` file from

```
- (void)deviceOrientationDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification { 

 NSLog(@"in device orientation ");
    UIView *superview = self.superview;
    if (!superview) {
        return;
    } else if ([superview isKindOfClass:[UIWindow class]]) {  // here changes have done
        [self setTransformForCurrentOrientation:YES];
    } else {
        self.bounds = self.superview.bounds;
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}
```

to:

```
- (void)deviceOrientationDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification { 

 NSLog(@"in device orientation ");
    UIView *superview = self.superview;
    if (!superview) {
        return;
    } else if ([superview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
        [self setTransformForCurrentOrientation:YES];
    } else {
        self.bounds = self.superview.bounds;
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}
```

How can I get the loading indicator to rotate with device orientation?

Comment: Note that if you rename your image DefaultPad.png to Default~ipad.png, you can leave out your if statement in your first code snippet, as the system automatically recognizes and displays it on iPad.

Answer (score 3):

In MBProgressHUD.m I changed

`UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;`

to

`UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];`

The orientation notification had been received, but the statusBar had not rotated yet.

Answer (score 2):

Try This:-

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
       //code for portrait
  [hud release];
  hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc]initWithView:splashView];
    }       
    else 
    { 
       //code for Landscape 
  [hud release];
  hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc]initWithView:splashView];
    }
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || 
            interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || 
            interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
            interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

if it does not work..
you can change the `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` with `UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification`in the source code of MBProgressHUD:-

```
- (id)initWithView:(UIView *)view {
        // Let's check if the view is nil (this is a common error when using the windw initializer above)
        if (!view) {
                [NSException raise:@"MBProgressHUDViewIsNillException" 
                                        format:@"The view used in the MBProgressHUD initializer is nil."];
        }
        id me = [self initWithFrame:view.bounds];
        // We need to take care of rotation ourselfs if we're adding the HUD to a window
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIWindow class]]) {
                [self setTransformForCurrentOrientation:NO];
        }
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(deviceOrientationDidChange:) 
                                                                                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];

        return me;
}
```

In the above code change UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotificationwith UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification.

It is just a work-around as rotation issue was always there with MBProgressHud .

I Guess MBProgressHud  is giving a lo of problems , you should instead switch to [svprogresshud](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD) as it handles orientations well

Comment: well the changes i suggeted did work for m.. i think u did not change the notification type...in the source code of the mbprogresshud ...please see the edits

Comment: you might have the souce code with you of mbprogressHUD so do it there in the init method i showed in my edits

Comment: Damn...Yarr use svprogresshud..can't help more on the MBProgressHud as these are tweaks to do to get it working in orientation

Comment: I think svprogresshud doesn't support orientation.

Comment: did you go to svprogresshud ..it does[see](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD#readme)

Comment: yeah firstly I have used it and it was not supporting device orientation thats why I used MBProgresshud

Comment: I added what you suggested and It works fine. Thanks. +1 vote
I changed as following,

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(deviceOrientationDidChange:) name:UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification object:nil];